# animate.css and remove the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animate.css

I want to display the animation that I have and also remove the element from the DOM, however by removing `this` the animation does not show.

I have tried using the `setTimeout()` function but as I need to target a specific element I cannot work out how to get both to execute!

here is the code:

```
function anagramHitsTheBottom () {
  $('.anagram').each(function () {
    const position = Math.round($(this).position().top);
    if (position >= 450) {
    console.log(lifeScore);
    lifeScore -= 1;
    $lives.html(Lives Left: ${lifeScore});//Not Working
    $(this).css('color','red');
    $(this).addClass('animated hinge');
    $(this).remove();
    }
  });
}
```

please ignore that I haven't used backticks in the ${} I know I need them!

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you missing: You are adding the animation to the element and at the same time, you're removing it from your document.

You could use this [extension](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css#custom-builds)(scroll a little bit up) for jQuery

```
$.fn.extend({
animateCss: function (animationName, callback) {
    var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
    this.addClass('animated ' + animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
        var obj = $(this);
        obj.removeClass('animated ' + animationName);
        if(callback && typeof callback === 'function') callback(obj);
    });
  }
});
```

This will make the animation run just one time and then you can use a callback to remove the element.

```
$(this).animateCss('hinge', function (obj) {
    //This will execute at the end of the animation
    obj.remove();
});
```